# VS Code, syntax highlighting for razor, server side comments

Tags: razor, syntax, visual-studio-code

With the recent release of VS Code it now seems to support razor syntax.  However it fails to highlight properly server side comments.  For example stuff like

```
@*<div>
Simple text 
</div>*@
```

Are not highlighted properly.